# WordPress Thematic framework - worth using?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been examining the Thematic Theme Framework for WordPress (http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/thematic).  I just got a job at a shop that does a fair amount of WP hacks and I'm examining Thematic for use as part of our 'standard procedures'.  I have themed WP a few times, just by copying twentyten or twentyeleven and then modifying it, but I'm at a point where I need to get deeper into WP to start overriding and really extending it (my PHP skills are decent).  My question is: in your opinion, is Thematic worth using?  My concerns are:

- performance hits on shared hosting where PHP is being run as a CGI binary and performance may already be not-so-hot
- what is the point of hooking into Thematic's functions (that hook into WordPress) instead of just hooking directly into WordPress?
- if the Thematic project is abandoned because the developers all die in a plane crash a la Lynyrd Skynyrd (or for other reasons) where does that leave me?

I'm just having trouble seeing the advantages to using Thematic - what does it offer that WordPress doesn't do already?  I'm looking for a justification for learning development with Thematic instead of just learning WordPress development directly.

All your rants are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed http://reesenews.org/ on WordPress. We thought about using Thematic but all of the functionality I need was already built into WordPress. Really, the answer to your question is, which site do you want to be looking at more? The WordPress codex or the Thematic website?

I found that I'd rather be learning WordPress functions and using the WordPress product itself rather than adding another layer of complexity with a theme framework. If your PHP skills are decent you will probably feel the same way that I did.

Once you feel comfortable as a theme developer you won't regret learning the WordPress codex.

Comment: Yeah, that was my train of thought exactly: why add another layer of complexity unless it justifies itself with significant and measurable benefits?

Answer (score 0):

I used Thematic for numerous sites. I really enjoy using it. I find that once you get used to it, it is a rapid system to develop with. However, I don't know how well it scales. The community and support are great though. One thing it lacks is built in responsive-ness for mobile devices into the default thematic package, but it is something they are working on. 
I built www.openproduct.cc and www.thatemilychappell.com with it. Simple examples but at least some  examples!

Comment: Those are nice clean sites.  Would you say that you find developing with Thematic is faster than developing with the built in WP functions?

Comment: It is faster for me because I have a library of filters and actions that I use in the functions.php file so it keeps everything in one place. Probably not so good for really huge projects, but you can still use file-based templates too. I recommend http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ and http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ plugins too.